# QML combobox showing incorrect value

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

```
ComboBox {  
    anchors.fill: parent  
    model: rangeList  
    currentIndex: 1
}
```

`rangeList` contains `1,2,3` as data and `currentIndex` is `1`. But when I run the UI it always takes `currentindex` as `0`. Can anyone tell why it is taking `currentIndex` as `0` instead of `1`.

```
ListModel { id: rangeList 
    ListElement { name: "1" }
    ListElement { name: "2" }
    ListElement { name: "3" }
    ListElement { name: "4" }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please provide the minimal part of your code that really reproduces your error. I set the model to  `[1,2,3]` and as expected, the initial selection is `2`

Comment: Please show how you create the `rangeList`. I guess the problem resides within that piece of code, hidden from us.

Comment: Have you tried the code, exactly as you posted it? My `ComboBox` shows correctly `2` upon startup when I copy both into the same `Window`.

Comment: Have you checked the output for any warning from the QML engine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the index using `onCompleted` which is emitted after the object has been instantiated.

```
ComboBox {  
    anchors.fill: parent  
    model: rangeList  
    Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = 1
}
```